# DUE schematic doubt Altium

Tags: altium, eaglecad

I have the schematic of Arduino DUE for EAGLE software, I found a part I dont know what means for Altium Software.

Can somebody tell me what is it "ETH" ? A header??

[Arduino Due schematic](https://content.arduino.cc/assets/DUE_V02g_sch.pdf)

[image]

I found this schematic Altium on Internet

[DUE Altium](https://i.imgur.com/7rcaBjz.png)

Comment: Where did you find the schematic, can you add a link to it?

Comment: Based on the signal names, it is almost certainly 'Ethernet'

Comment: How do you even make something like that in Altium? I thought people who like to hide power pins were bad enough.

Comment: Arduino official page I found schematics

Answer (score 3):

That is almost certainly Ethernet that appears to go to a connector of some description. This is the [RMII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media-independent_interface) or RGMII port (That is clear from the two data bits in each direction rather than 4)

The signal naming convention seems to be:

**E** (Ethernet)

**Signal direction** for signals that have specific direction: TX (Transmit), RX (Receive)

**Signal name**

**Port ID** This is all on ethernet port **A**

So **ETXD0A** is Ethernet, Transmit, D0 (data bit zero), port A.

Comment: The Cortex chip has a 16 pin Ethernet interface. Two of the pins seem to be missing from that diagram?

Comment: RXDV and CRS are multiplexed in RMII and COL is omitted in RMII. One of the unlabelled connections is MDC.